# sqoop2 client batch mode script example

Tags: cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-cdh, sqoop2

Can anyone show me an example of script that can be run from sqoop2 client in batch mode?

I refered http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.2/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html

and it says we can run sqoop2 client in batch mode using the following command

`sqoop.sh client /path/to/your/script.sqoop`

but that script.sqoop isn't like sqoop1 script, so how should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Batch file is nothing but a list of the same commands you would otherwise type in interactive mode (plus comment lines starting with pound sign).
However! Some commands require manual input, thus cannot be easily fully automated (e.g., 'create link' command). See [this](http://grokbase.com/t/sqoop/user/139bbc2q41/sqoop-2-and-batch-mode) thread for details.